# Getting SessionFactory in hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta5.jar

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am trying to initialize the SessionFactory using hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta5.jar. 
But i am getting the java.lang.NullPointerException.

Below is my code

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static final  SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().withOptions().openSession();
        System.out.println(session.isConnected());
    }
```

This is the exception

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hibernate4.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1839)
    at hibernate4.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-testing/4.3.0.Beta5/org/hibernate/testing/junit4/BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.java

A testcase from hibernate.

In simple words:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();

    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something which your are missing:

buildServiceRegistry() instead of build()

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: No. We have to use build() instead of buildServiceRegistry() in hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta5.jar